# Collection data from different pages for a list of data and sending them together

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, q

I have an array of publishers and each publisher have motionID, this ID is used to get data from API Like

```
'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page='
```

publisher.motion is motionID. Every publisher of the motion have multiple pages of event.

```
'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page=1'
'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page=2'
 .
 .
'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page=n'
```

I want to collected all the events from all pages of motion and save to that publisher.motionEvent array.And I also want to call another function when all data is collected for all publishers. And Publisher are push into allProduct array

My Code:

```
getEventsOfPublishes(objectList,'M')

}).then(function(allPublisherWithMotionEvents){
    console.log(allPublisherWithMotionEvents)
})
```

here objectList is all publisher which have motionID as there Property.

```
function getEventsOfPublishes(objectList,key){
    if(objectList.length){
        if(key == 'M'){
            var promises = objectList.map(getEventsOfMotion);
            return Q.all(promises);
        }

    }else{
        return {msg:"No Objects"};
    }

}
```

using q.map for calling function for each publisher.

```
function getEventsOfMotion(publisher){

    if(publisher.motion !== undefined){
        //console.log('motion')
        url = 'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page=';
        publisher.motionEvent = []
        getAllDataOfEvents(1,url,'M',publisher).then(function(test){
            allProducts.push(test)
        //console.log(test)
        })

    }else{
        console.log('yes')
    }
}
```

calling function 'getAllDataOfEvents' for those publisher which have motion Id, as there property.

```
function getAllDataOfEvents(currentPage,url,key,publisher){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var result
    httprequest(url+currentPage,
        function(err, res, body) {
            var events = JSON.parse(body);
            var next;
            var tempDeviceObject = {}
            // console.log(events.objects)
            saveProducts(events.objects,key,publisher)
            if(events.links.next != null){
                currentPage++
                getAllDataOfEvents(currentPage,url,key,publisher).then(function(){
                    deferred.resolve(publisher)
                });
            }else{
                result =  deferred.resolve(publisher);
            } 
       })

    return deferred.promise;
}


function saveProducts(objects,key,publisher){
    if(key === 'M'){
        if(objects){
            //console.log(objects.length+'---------'+publisher.motion)
            objects.forEach(function (event) {
                var tempEventobject = {}
                tempEventobject.date = event.dateEvent;
                tempEventobject.durationSeconds = event.data.durationSeconds
                tempEventobject.numberMovements = event.data.numberMovements
                tempEventobject.avgIntensity = event.data.avgIntensity
                tempEventobject.eventID = publisher.motion

                publisher.motionEvent.push(tempEventobject)
            })
            //console.log(publisher);
        }
    }else{
    //    console.log(publisher)
    }
}
```

In the above code all events are collected in publisher.motionEvent, but allPublisherWithMotionEvents is array of undefined i.e the function is not waiting for that to be collected. I have used Q module.
Thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor mistake in your code that is **getEventsOfMotion** is not returning promise, replace it with following one:

```
function getEventsOfMotion(publisher){
    var defer = q.defer();
    if(publisher.motion !== undefined){
        //console.log('motion')
        url = 'https://example.com/v2/feeds/'+publisher.motion+'/events/?page=';
        publisher.motionEvent = []
        getAllDataOfEvents(1,url,'M',publisher).then(function(test){
            allProducts.push(test);
            defer.resolve();
        //console.log(test)
        })

    }else{
        console.log('yes')
    }
 return defer.promise()
}
```

Happy Helping!